# Context2d arc() with begin path, generates strange circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to write a game engine in pure javscript and canvas.
I got a strange thing today, while generating a circle with

```
var circle = new Circle(10, 10, 100);
```

The circle is weird, if I remove from the code `beginPath()` and `closePath()` and it works as it should, but then the screen is not redraw due to: http://codetheory.in/why-clearrect-might-not-be-clearing-canvas-pixels/

The "engine" code can be found here: [insane96mcp.altervista.org/Invaders/script.js](http://insane96mcp.altervista.org/Invaders/script.js)

[image: Strange circle]

Comment: Read the docs about closePath, I giess you got it wrong.

Comment: Yep, that's one weird circle. But please post the [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code here if you want help fixing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce your weird circle from the code in your link, but...

**1. You appear to have misconceptions about `beginPath` & `endPath`**

`beginPath` starts a new path and stops drawing the previous path. It is necessary to prevent your drawings from accumulating and overwriting themselves. Without beginPath your circle will redraw (& redraw & redraw & redraw!) itself with every call to `yourCircle.Draw`. *This constant redrawing might be causing your weird circle if you leave out `beginPath`.*

`closePath` is **not** the counter-part to beginPath. It does not stop drawing a path. Instead it simply connects the current path position to the beginning path position with a line. *Without `beginPath`, these extra lines created by `closePath` might be the cause of your jagged circle.*

Some reading for you below (context.beginPath and context.closePath)

**2. You're un-necessarily adding "empty" `Shape` objects into `gameObjects` in your `function Shape`.**

**3. ...And yes, as you surmise in your question, if you're not clearing the canvas between draws with `clearRect` then your drawings will accumulate. But one would expect the circle to be more uniformly fuzzy instead of jaggedy.**

---

**context.beginPath**

```
context.beginPath()
```

Begins assembling a new set of path commands and also discards any previously assembled path.

It also moves the drawing "pen" to the top-left origin of the canvas (==coordinate[0,0]).

**Although optional, you should ALWAYS start a path with `beginPath`**

The discarding is an important and often overlooked point. If you don't begin a new path with `beginPath`, any previously issued path commands will automatically be redrawn.

These 2 demos both attempt to draw an "X" with one red stroke and one blue stroke.

This first demo correctly uses `beginPath` to start it's second red stroke. The result is that the "X" correctly has both a red and a blue stroke.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{ background-color:white; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red; }
</style>
<script>
window.onload=(function(){

    // get a reference to the canvas element and it's context
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw a blue line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(30,30);
    ctx.lineTo(100,100);
    ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.stroke();

    // draw a red line
    ctx.beginPath();        // Important to begin a new path! 
    ctx.moveTo(100,30);
    ctx.lineTo(30,100);
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.stroke();

}); // end window.onload
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=150></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

This second demo incorrectly leaves out `beginPath` on the second stroke. The result is that the "X" incorrectly has both red strokes.

The second `stroke()` is draws the second red stroke.

But without a second `beginPath`, that same second `stroke()` also incorrectly **redraws** the first stroke.

Since the second `stroke()` is now styled as red, the first blue stroke is **overwritten** by an incorrectly colored red stroke.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{ background-color:white; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red; }
</style>
<script>
window.onload=(function(){

    // get a reference to the canvas element and it's context
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw a blue line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(30,30);
    ctx.lineTo(100,100);
    ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.stroke();

    // draw a red line
    // Note: The necessary 'beginPath' is missing! 
    ctx.moveTo(100,30);
    ctx.lineTo(30,100);
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.stroke();

}); // end window.onload
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=150></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**context.closePath**

```
context.closePath()
```

Draws a line from the current pen location back to the beginning path coordinate.

For example, if you draw 2 lines forming 2 legs of a triangle, closePath will "close" the triangle by drawing the third leg of the triangle from the 2nd leg's endpoint back to the first leg's starting point.

**A Misconception explained!**

This command's name often causes it to be misunderstood.

`context.closePath` is NOT an ending delimiter to `context.beginPath`.

Again, the closePath command draws a line -- it does not "close" a beginPath.

This example draws 2 legs of a triangle and uses `closePath` to complete (close?!) the triangle by drawing the third leg. What `closePath` is actually doing is drawing a line from the second leg's endpoint back to the first leg's starting point.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{ background-color:white; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red; }
</style>
<script>
window.onload=(function(){

    // get a reference to the canvas element and it's context
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // arguments
    var topVertexX=50;
    var topVertexY=50;
    var rightVertexX=75;
    var rightVertexY=75;
    var leftVertexX=25;
    var leftVertexY=75;

    // A set of line segments drawn to form a triangle using
    //     "moveTo" and multiple "lineTo" commands
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(topVertexX,topVertexY);
    ctx.lineTo(rightVertexX,rightVertexY);
    ctx.lineTo(leftVertexX,leftVertexY);

    // closePath draws the 3rd leg of the triangle
    ctx.closePath()

    ctx.stroke();

}); // end window.onload
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=150></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I had a misconception about `closePath()`. Seems that `closePath()` were causing it.
And thanks for the other tips.